# How do I lower my touchpad scroll speed?

Tags: touchpad, macbook-pro, 22.10

I'm on a 2012 Macbook Pro with Ubuntu installed. Whenever I scroll with the touchpad it goes way too fast. Any idea how to fix this? I did a bit of research but none of it seems to work.
Here is the output of sudo xinput list

```
    WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:14                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:14              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:14              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:14                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I’m using 22.10 but it seems to be happening to people on 22.04 too.

Comment: I fixed the tags, I’m using 22.10 but it seems to be happening to people on 22.04 too.